# Adding If Condition

Tags: jquery

I'm new in using jquery and i would like to ask what do you call this kind of statement where I want to add an If Statement inside

btw. the Read here is Boolean and i want to change if `Read == true` `read: 'read'` and if false it becomes `unread: 'unread'`

This is my Original code:

```
var options = { id: ID,
                read: Read == true ? 'unread' : 'read',
                category: "projects",
                message: Message
                };
```

and my Trial but didn't succeeded :

```
var options = { 
       if(Read == true) { 
                    id: ID,
                    read: 'read',
                    category: "projects",
                    message: Message
                        } 
        else {
                    id: ID,
                    unread: 'unread',
                    category: "projects",
                    message: Message
             }
    };
```

having `expected identifier or string` in the `if` word

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Tell us what is Read.. Add some more info..

Comment: use ternary as opted by Claudix. Also, don't change property names for "read/unread", only the value (true/false i would choose myself). Makes your life so much easier to access it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary operator:

```
(expression_to_test) ? (value_if_true) : (value_if_false)

var options =  
    (Read == true) ? { 
                         id: ID,
                         read: 'read',
                         category: "projects",
                         message: Message
                    } 
                   : {
                        id: ID,
                        unread: 'unread',
                        category: "projects",
                        message: Message
                   }
;
```

**NOTICE**

The curly braces {} are NOT part of the ternary operator syntax. They are used here to create inline objects. In the code above, if `Read == true` then the operator returns the object created by the first curly braces.

Comment: btw sir I just want to ask what do you called this kind of sequence ? kinda new with this

Comment: The {} are intended to create an object. They are not for syntax purposes.

Comment: @EnriqueGil, this is called ternary operator and it's used in other languages such as C.

Comment: @Claudix - ah, yep see that now was looking at it like a normal if statement

Comment: Can i  add an Alert statement inside the ternary operators?

Comment: Yes you can. You can call functions both in the conditional expression and true/false values. The result of the operator will be the value returned by the eventually called function.

Answer (score 0):

If Read is a boolean then:

```
var Read = false;    
var options = { 
       id: 12,
       read: Read ? 'unread' : 'read',
       category: "projects",
       message: 'msg'
   };

console.log(options); // {id: 12, read: "read", category: "projects", message: "msg"} 

Read = true;
options = { 
       id: 12,
       read: Read ? 'unread' : 'read',
       category: "projects",
       message: 'msg'
   };

console.log(options); // {id: 12, read: "unread", category: "projects", message: "msg"}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntzLb02b/)**

But it seems to me Read isn't a boolean, since if it was, then your original code would work:

```
var Read = false;    
var options = { 
       id: 12,
       read: Read == true ? 'unread' : 'read',
       category: "projects",
       message: 'msg'
   };

console.log(options); // {id: 12, read: "read", category: "projects", message: "msg"} 

Read = true;
options = { 
       id: 12,
       read: Read == true ? 'unread' : 'read',
       category: "projects",
       message: 'msg'
   };

console.log(options); // {id: 12, read: "unread", category: "projects", message: "msg"}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhf5smz6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator like Claudix said, but;

Don't change the "structure of the options" if there is not structural difference. The difference is "is it read or not" => which should be represented by a single property on the options.

```
   var options = { 
                 id: ID,
                 read: Read,
                 category: "projects",
                 message: Message
              };
```

anywhere in your code you can now do a 'simple' if to check if it has been read.

```
   if (options.read) {
      // it was read
   } else {
      // it was not read yet.
   }
```

preventing the need of the "unread" property and "read/unread" string comparison.